# Cannot start RIDE.py in ubuntu after the installation

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, robotframework

Could you please help to solve this problem.
I have installed Python2.7, Selenium2Library, WXPython; Robot Framework...
when I want to start the Ride I got the following error.

```
:~$ ride.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/__init__.py", line 74, in main
    _run(inpath, not noupdatecheck, debug_console)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/__init__.py", line 100, in _run
    ride = RIDE(inpath, updatecheck)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/application/application.py", line 42, in __init__
    wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8628, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/application/application.py", line 47, in OnInit
    self.settings = RideSettings()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/preferences/settings.py", line 316, in __init__
    user_path = initialize_settings(default_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/preferences/settings.py", line 29, in initialize_settings
    SETTINGS_DIRECTORY, path, dest_file_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/preferences/settings.py", line 46, in _copy_or_migrate_user_settings
    SettingsMigrator(source_path, settings_path).migrate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/preferences/settings.py", line 94, in migrate
    self.merge()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/preferences/settings.py", line 98, in merge
    self._write_merged_settings(self._default_settings, self._user_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/preferences/settings.py", line 186, in _write_merged_settings
    'Could not open settings file "%s" for writing' % path)
RuntimeError: Could not open settings file "/home/said/.robotframework/ride/settings.cfg" for writing
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear:
    RuntimeError: Could not open settings file "/home/said/.robotframework/ride/settings.cfg" for writing

Possible solutions:

1. cd ; pwd ;
   /home/said
2. rm -rf .robotframework

or

2. sudo chown -R said:said .robotframework

Comment: Thanks Helio for your help. Now I can start my Ride.py but, still a little problem which related to the version of wxPython:                                   Please be aware of untested wxPython installation RIDE officially supports wxPython 2.8.12.1. Your current version is 3.0.2.0.There are significant changes in newer wxPython versions. Notice that RIDE is still under development for wxPython 3.0.2 and newer (wxPython-Phoenix). wxPython 2.8.12.1 packages can be found from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/.

Comment: You are using the beta version of RIDE. You may remove that message by editing code, or by installing wxPython 2.8.12.1.